# How to store python dict of lists in redis?

Tags: python, redis

I have a python dictionary in which every key corresponds to a vector-id and the value contains an n dimensional vector as a list. I want to store and retrieve the data to perform mathematical operations. 
e.g.

```
{
1121:[5.333,1.637,3.323],
3442:[1.32,0.233,4.04],
.
.
.

}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no one way to do that. First, note that Redis' data structures are not nest-able. Then, decide what patterns you need to serve with the data.

1. If you're mostly reading/writing the entire dictionary, the simplest is to serialize it (using Pickle, JSON or whatever) and store it as a plain String key in Redis.
2. If you're accessing only individual vectors, you can mimic the dictionary structure using a Redis Hash, in which each field is a vector id and the value is the serialized list.

Comment: Or you can use the excellent ReJSON module that will let you store JSON objects in redis and manipulate them directly. https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/rejson

Comment: Avoid pickle at any rate it introduces security breach.